# How to force protobuf to recognize the right Python version?

Tags: python, python-3.x, protocol-buffers, gcloud

I'm trying to run a pip3 install on a linux server. When running the command I get an error stating that protobuf can't run because the python version is too low. However this is not true, as the python version is above what protobuf is asking for.

```
protobuf requires Python '>=3.7' but the running Python is 3.6.8
[userID@linuxServer ~]$ python --version
Python 3.8.13
[userID@linuxServer ~]$
```

I am trying to install gcloud.

Is there a config file somewhere that will point protobuf to the right version? Or is there some way to ignore protobuf?

Comment: I'm confused by your question. Are you trying to install [gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk) or trying to `pip3 install something-else`? Or are you perhaps trying to `pip install gcloud`? If so, you should probably `pip install google-cloud`. If you're trying to install a package, one way to overcome the weird error would be to create a virtualenv using your python 3.8.13 version and then use pip within it.

Comment: @DazWilkin I'm trying to install gcloud using pip3. The command would be "pip3 install gcloud". I've tried to install google-cloud as well. Same error. Anything I pip results in that error. How can I create a virtual env?

Comment: Can you successfully run `python -m venv ${PWD}/venv && source ${PWD}/venv/bin/activate`? The second `venv` reference in the first command specifies the directory where the virtual environment is created.

Comment: @DazWilkin Yes I was able to run both commands. I created the venv and was able to run the pip3 command without protobuf getting in the way. But, if I exit the venv, the original problem persist. Is there a way for the changes I make in the venv to be permanent? Or will I have to enter the venv every time I want to do something?

Comment: Great. You will need to `source` the virtualenv after closing the shell or `deactivate`'ing it. It's good practice to use  virtualenv as a way to encapsulate Python development environments, keep them in known-good state and distinct. It's unclear why your base environment is causing problems and virtualenv proves its worth.

Comment: @DazWilkin Every time I need to run whatever scripts I'm running, I'll need to add ```source ${PWD}/venv/bin/activate```? Ok, that's not too much of a burden. My sysadmin setup the base env, not sure why it isn't working properly, but haven't been able to get it fixed in a week. Thanks for the help buddy!